# Hosting a Remote Node

Tags: full-node

Are there specific parameters you need to use in order to host a remote node for the Wallet gui? how does one host a remote note?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to run a publicly avaiable server (either with a public address, or with a NAT on a router/firewall) with a monerod running on it, that expose ports 18080 & 18081 over the Internet.

Biggest requirement will be the hard drive space to hold the copy of the blockchain.

Comment: Perfect thanks, Just thought that I needed some sort of parameter command for the monerod

Comment: Btw, you obviously need to specify the `--rpc-bind-ip <your_server_ip>` and `--confirm-external-bind` but it's the same as a full node on your local network.